# Wrong time on Thunderbird

Tags: time

The time on the PC is correct but the time on Thunderbird is not. How can I sync Thunderbird time with that of PC?

Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Which time do you mean exactly?

Comment: The time of when emails are received does not correspond with actual local time.

Comment: How much is it off?

Comment: I think it is close to 12 hours. All times are from from 00:00 to 12:59 and there isn't  AM or PM.

Comment: Quit Thunderbird, press Alt+F2, enter `thunderbird -P` and create a new profile. Then start Thunderbird using the new profile, testwise connect to your mail server and see whether the time is correct.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I did that but the new profile still shows the time as above. The time is right but it is always depicted from 00:00 to 12:59 without Am or PM.